# Crystal Report Functions

Tags: crystal-reports, report

i'm new to crystal report and now having problem displaying string from function.

here's the data that will pass to crystal report.

```
**Class**   **Type**    **PAccess** **Haccess**
Executive   Principal   With Major  Yes
Manager     Dependent   W/o Major   Yes
```

Now, i want to display it like this.

Executive - Principal

If {PAccess} = "With Major" then

1. Major 1 (HardCoded in the Function)
2. Major 2 (HardCoded in the Function)
3. Major 3 (HardCoded in the Function)

else

Without Major

```
Base on the data, output should be liked this.

Executive - Principal
1. Major 1
2. Major 2
3. Major 3

Manager - Dependent
Without Major
```

Comment: where do you need to display the info? I mean to say in which part of the report, Also if condition pass or fail where should be the info? under Executive or under principal

Comment: the info (Major 1, Major 2..) will display under Executive-Principal if the condition pass else "Without Major" will be displayed. same with Manager Dependent. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a formula; in that formula add {ado.class} & " - " & {ado.type} (note: ado... is your column) This will give you a header like Executive - Principal
2. Create a group of above formula.
3. In detail section add one more formula; In that write

> ```
> If  {PAccess} = "With Major" then 
> "1. Major 1" & chr(13) & 
> "2. Major 2" & chr(13) & 
> "3. Major  3"
> else "Without Major"
> ```

Comment: note: formula might go wrong in syntax as it is not checked. if failed then try to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now follow below process:

1. Create a group with `Executive`
2. Now in group header create two text fields and write `Executive -
   Principal`
3. In detail write your formula.

This will solve your issue.